# Zero Code Coverage on Custom Button ListView Record Update

Tags: apex, code-coverage, list-view

hoping I can get some help. I'm drawing a zero response in code coverage.

I have a Custom Button that updates the status of a custom object on it related master object page.

I am getting absolutely no code coverage. I'm guessing it may have to do with Instantiating the Class Controller, however, still cannot figure it out.

Your direction is greatly appreciated!

Here is the Apex Code

```
 public with sharing class SurveySentController 
{
   private ApexPages.StandardSetController standardController;

   public SurveySentController(ApexPages.StandardSetController standardController)
   {
    this.standardController = standardController;
   }

public PageReference checkSurveySent()
{       
    // Get the selected records (optional, you can use getSelected to obtain ID's and do your own SOQL)
    List<Outreach_Visit_Attendee__c> selectedAttendees = (List<Outreach_Visit_Attendee__c>) standardController.getSelected();

    // Update records       
    for(Outreach_Visit_Attendee__c selectedAttendee : selectedAttendees)
    {
        if(selectedAttendee.Survey_Sent__c == null) 
            selectedAttendee.Survey_Sent__c = true;
        else if(selectedAttendee.Survey_Sent__c == false)
            selectedAttendee.Survey_Sent__c = true;

    }       

    return null;        
}

public PageReference updateAttendees()
{       
    // Call StandardSetController 'save' method to update (optional, you can use your own DML)

    return standardController.save();  
    return standardController.cancel(); 
}
```

}

Here is the VFP
[image]

Here is my UPDATED Test Class

```
@isTest
public class SurveySentControllerTest{
public static TestMethod void TestSurveySentController(){

        //Create and insert an Outreach Visit Attendee
        Outreach_Visit_Attendee__c attend = new Outreach_Visit_Attendee__c 
                (Attendee_Name__c = 'test name', Outreach_Visit__c = 'test visit', survey_sent__c = false);
        insert attend;

        List <Outreach_Visit_Attendee__c> selectedAttendee = [Select Attendee_Name__c, Outreach_Visit__c, survey_sent__c from Outreach_Visit_Attendee__c WHERE Attendee_Name__c != NULL];

        ApexPages.StandardSetController standardController = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(attend);
        SurveySentController  sv = new SurveySentController (standardController);

        sv.checkSurveySent();
        sv..updateAttendees() ;

        sv.checkSurveySent();
        sv.updateAttendees() ;


 }

}
```

Comment: can you also call ** checkSurveySent** method?
And I can not believe that there is 0% code coverage -- at least constructor is covered

Comment: add following line before assert statements stdSetController.checkSurveySent(); stdSetController.updateAttendees()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these lines in code

```
ApexPages.StandardSetController standardController = new ApexPages.StandardSetControllerr(selectedAttendee)
 standardController.setSelected(selectedAttendee);
SurveySentController  sv = new SurveySentController (standardController);

sv.checkSurveySent();
sv..updateAttendees() ;
```

You will get most lines covered for remaining one match the condition and you will get good coverage.

Comment: thank you for your note. I am getting an error message "unexpected token: 'standardController' " on the first line. Also, should I use "newAttendees" instead of "attend"?

Comment: i've added the updated/cleaner code, however, I'm still getting error message as noted above "unexpected token: 'standardController ". Any ideas on how to solve for the error message?

Comment: @tomc0920  I have update my code.

Comment: it may be getting close. here is another error message with updated code: Constructor not defined: [ApexPages.StandardSetController].<Constructor>(Outreach_Visit_Attendee__c)

Comment: Check the update code.

Comment: sorry to say, even with the updated code (selectedAttendee [0]), i'm still getting: Constructor not defined: [ApexPages.StandardSetController].<Constructor>(Outreach_Visit_Attendee__c).  Appreciate your help...

Comment: @tomc0920 I have update my code and test this > check if it is work for you.

Comment: @thushar, thank you! that did it, resulting in 85%. I will get the remaining to push to 100%. Very much appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Update your StandardSetController initialization as below

```
ApexPages.StandardSetController standardController = new ApexPages.StandardSetControllerr(selectedAttendee);
```

It expects a List of records, not a single instance.

You can refer more details here about StandardSetController
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_pages_standardsetcontroller.htm